# Network Manager requires frequent restarting to access the internet when connected via a mobile hotspot

Tags: release-hera, wifi, networking, kernel

When connected to a mobile hotspot, after 15 minutes or so, I need to restart the Network Manager to access the internet. Wifi shows connected to the network but Firefox shows no internet. This happens frequently if I don't use the internet.

System configuration

1. **Kernel** - Linux 5.4.0-42-generic
2. **OS** - elementary OS 5.1.6 Hera
3. **Laptop** - Dell Inspiron 7075
4. **CPU** - Intel 8th gen i7 -  8550U

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this issue manifests itself when connection details to the internet differ from what was provided during the connection to the network itself. Essentially, mobile hotspots are subject to constant changes. While your connection to the network (the phone/hotspot) will remain active and constant, the connection to your carrier is always in flux. Your device will go through many shifts including IP and other routing changes that will at some point cause reliant devices like your laptop to be unable to access data beyond the local network itself without re-establishing a connection with proper details.